# My Dell Inspiron 1501 wont connect to any network (wireless or wired)

Tags: networking, dell, connection, inspiron

I just recently installed Ubuntu 12.04, replacing windows vista on my Inspiron and it wont connect to the internet by any means. It won't detect any wireless networks and when I try the ethernet cord, I can see "wired connection 1" in the network manager but the symbol on the panel is a wireless signal with 0 bars. Furthermore when I open firefox, it says there isn't a connection. What should I do?

---

(NOT AN ANSWER)
Ok so I've entered the required information, and changed the router settings so that it uses a static IP. Still the Inspiron refuses to recognize the connection. When I pull up the network manager, the only connection I see is "Wired Connection 1" but it says it was last used one day ago even though I currently have it plugged in. It's like the computer doesn't even recognise the attached ethernet cord.

Comment: Regarding wireless not working, check to see if you've enabled the wireless drivers in Jockey (Alt-F2 / jockey-gtk / Enter).  AS for the wired, check and make sure that your router is working, doesn't have MAC address filtering or anything funky enabled.

Comment: I'm not sure if i've got anything funky enabled on my router, it should be on the default settings. The router does work on my Dell Inspiron N5030. So I would think the problem lies within the Inspiron 1501.

Comment: Well if u are using wired connection, for sure you need to enter the network settings(IP address, subnet, gateway etc.) only exception being DHCP connection.

Comment: How would I go about finding this information?

Comment: You can find the information from your network provider. They give a unique IP address, Subnet, gateway etc. settings for each connection.It must have been saved in your vista, and you must have  forgot to note it down before wiping vista.

Answer (score 1):

well.. my inspiron 1501 has a broadcom card.. you probably have the same card..

Run these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

**Then unplug ethernet and reboot**

Answer (score 0):

Well if u are using wired connection, for sure you need to enter the network settings(IP address, subnet, gateway etc.) only exception being DHCP connection.So all u need to to do is go to network manager, click on 'Wired connection 1' then to go `IPv4` I am assuming you are having a IPv4 connection. Then Go to manual [image: Screenshot of Network settings].I have network setting filled, you also check your appropriate network settings and fill them out.
Once done everything should work like a charm.