# Dell Inspiron 1501 no wired/wireless w/12.04 or13.04

Tags: connection, wired

I don't know what to do. Every install of either 13.04 and 12.04 on my Dell does not have a working wired or wireless internet connection. However, if I am running from USB in the trial mode I have working internet through a wired connection using the same ethernet cord.

I honestly at this point do not know what I can do to fix this issue as I have gone through every possible fix I have found here and in other places.

Comment: Try clicking on the network icon then on Connect to hidden WiFi network, this may help. if not, can you tell us the make and model of your PC and the wireless card.

Comment: Laptop is a Dell Inspiron 1501 with a Broadcom Wireless card. Negative on the hidden WiFi network as well.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source` then `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` as in the following information page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: For this I would need a connection to the internet. As it stands I have neither a wired or a wireless connection.

Comment: This is a tricky one, just got up with a fresh head on, I'll try and find something that will help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/178844/my-dell-inspiron-1501-wont-connect-to-any-network-wireless-or-wired might give you some pointers, try resetting the router to a static IP address, or another useful answer is this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offlinehttp://askubuntu.com/questions/178844/my-dell-inspiron-1501-wont-connect-to-any-network-wireless-or-wired

Comment: Same laptop, same problem here, I tried 12.04 and 13.04. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue which I could not fix. I eventually fixed it using the method below.

In package manager remove bcmwl-kernal-source, then reboot. You should find the wired LAN connection then works.

To get the wireless working install linux-firmware-nonfree then reboot again. You will probably need to enable the adapter with Fn + F2 but should work after that.

Comment: Still broken on 14.04.  "apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source" does get wired LAN working, but linux-firmware-nonfree doesn't get WiFi back up.  Running the "Additional Drivers" tool in "Software & Updates" does detect the Broadcom WiFi module, but it re-installs bcmwl-kernel-source which doesn't work and which breaks ethernet again!